# Symbolic link of file on ftp server to file on dropbox

Tags: links, video, ftp

Can I create a symbolic link from an ftp server (file on website) to a Dropbox URL? I'm trying and it's seeming to work correctly. My problem is a video isn't playing correctly on my site, but I know it plays perfectly every time for the Dropbox URL. Rather than sendign out notification that the link has changed once more, I thought I could create a symlink to the new file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out I needed a different solution than what I was looking for. I added a `RedirectPermanent /old_page http//www.newawesomesite.com/old_page` to the .htaccess file, which cleared it up my problem nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike HTTP, the FTP protocol does not include any statuses that indicate that a resource has moved.  Here is the [list of all statuses that FTP servers can return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes).  None of the responses can indicate that a document has moved or is in a different location.

The best that you are going to be able to do is put a document in that location saying that the resource has moved.  If the ftp downloads are done using a web browser, they might honor a document with a meta refresh in it.  Put an HTML document there like this and see what happens:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://dropbox.com/myfile">
</head><body>
This document has moved to <a href="http://dropbox.com/myfile">http://dropbox.com/myfile</a>
</body></html>
```